# datatables button change/filter content based on variable sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables with the buttons plugin. I have two buttons that filter the content that is displayed based on a variable that I need to send to the server, so the ajax url has to change everytime I click one button.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    processing: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    ajax: {
        url: '/get?op=10',
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'surname' },
        { data: 'phone' },
        { data: 'email' },
        { data: 'nin' }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Everyone',
            // action ??
        },
        {
            text: 'Owners',
        },
        {
            text: 'Applicants',
        }
    ],
    select: true
});
```

The third button should reset the ajax url to the original one.

```
public function get_address_book_table($id, $owner = 0) {
    $mysqli = $this->aet->getAetSql();
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

    switch ($owner) {
        case 0: $a = $b = NULL; break;
        case 1: $a = 'pd.applicant_id'; $b = 'INNER JOIN property_demand pd ON pd.applicant_id = ab.id'; break;
        case 2: $a = 'po.owner_id';     $b = 'INNER JOIN property_owner po ON po.owner_id = ab.id'; break;
    }

    $query = 'SELECT ab.*, sab.*' . $a . '
              FROM address_book ab
              INNER JOIN staff_address_book sab ON sab.contact_id = ab.id' .
              $b . '
              WHERE sab.staff_id = ?';

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $surname, $phone, $email, $nin, $note, $a, $b);

        $data = [];
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $nestedData = [];
            $nestedData['id'] = $id;
            $nestedData['name'] = $name;
            $nestedData['surname'] = $surname;
            $nestedData['phone'] = $phone;
            $nestedData['email'] = $email;
            $nestedData['nin'] = $nin;
            $data[] = $nestedData;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

And the get file:

```
// address_book table
if ($op === 10) {

    $owner = isset( $_GET['owner'] ) ? (int) $_GET['owner'] : 0;
    $result = $functions->get_address_book_table($staff->getId(), $owner);

    header('Content-type: text/json');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

I'm looking for an option for the button plugin that allow me to change the ajax url on click so that the table is refreshed with the new server content.

Comment: So you wish someone to provide the code?  Try something (research if needed) then post that if you need assistance and we can then help you.

Comment: Yes sorry, I've already done the research (I just forgot mention it) but I didn't found anything useful. I've been reading in the documentation but I've only found examples for something that doesn't work: https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options The `sAjaxUrl` option, not sure how that works for the buttons plugin...

Comment: "This parameter is used by the Ajax button's default 'fnClick' function to define where the Ajax request should be sent."  some variation of `"oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "ajax",
                    "sAjaxUrl": "remote.php"
                }
            ]
        }` where ` "remote.php"` is some URL pointing to your `get_address_book_table($id, $owner = 0)` and we have no clue WHAT that would be for your site.

Comment: I just added where the ajax url points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a value in the button event, and pass that value as a parameter to the server. Finally, you probably want to trigger the ajax data reload when you click the button. Try something like this:

```
var filterType = 'all';
$('#example').DataTable( {
    processing: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
     serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/get',
        //dataSrc: 'data',
          data: function(d) {
            d.op = 10;
            d.filterType = filterType;
          }
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'surname' },
        { data: 'phone' },
        { data: 'email' },
        { data: 'nin' }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Everyone',
            action: function(e, dt) { filterType = 'all'; dt.ajax.reload(); }
        },
        {
            text: 'Owners',
            action: function(e, dt) { filterType = 'owner'; dt.ajax.reload(); }
        },
        {
            text: 'Applicants',
            action: function(e, dt) { filterType = 'app'; dt.ajax.reload(); }
        }
    ],
    select: true
});
```

Comment: About the serverside, it's because of the variable that needs to be sent, but if I send all the data at once to datables, would it be better to let datatables filter it? Can I do this without adding a new column? I mean in the database table, maybe a hidden column so that datatables knows how to filter?

Comment: Yes, perhaps I misunderstood what you were trying to do. In that case you would not need the `dt.ajax.refresh()`. Instead you would want to implement whatever kind of filter you have in mind...perhaps a [column filter](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html). Something like this: `dt.column(0).search('1').draw()`

Comment: I'll give it a try to both ways. Thanks!